# Adding an indicator at the current touch position?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a color selector and using a circular gradient and a `panGesture` to pick the color.

Can I add a crosshair or something else to the current touch position?

I need the crosshair to be visible but it should not interfere with the gradient.

This is the code that adds the gradient :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];





    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, ((self.view.bounds.size.height)/2));
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), YES, 0.0);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0,size.width,size.height));


    int sectors = 180;
    float radius = MIN(size.width, size.height)/2;
    float angle = 2 * M_PI/sectors;
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
    for ( int i = 0; i < sectors; i++)
    {
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(((size.width)/2), ((size.height)/2));
        bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:i * angle endAngle:(i + 1) * angle clockwise:YES];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint:center];
        [bezierPath closePath];
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:((float)i)/sectors saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];
        [color setFill];
        [color setStroke];
        [bezierPath fill];
        [bezierPath stroke];
    }
    img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    gradientView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

    colorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    colorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 00, 50, 50);


    rText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    gText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    bText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    saturationText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    alphaText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    brightnessText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    rText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    gText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    bText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

    saturationText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    alphaText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    brightnessText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;



    gradientView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:gradientView];
    gradientView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [gradientView addGestureRecognizer: panGesture];

    [self.view addSubview:colorView];





}
```

The handlePan method :

```
    - (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{


    if (sender.numberOfTouches)
        {
            CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, (self.view.bounds.size.height)/2);

            float radius = MIN(size.width, size.height)/2;

            [alphaSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(changeOpacity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [hellSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(changeBrightness:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [saturationSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(saturate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [rSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(redSlider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [gSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(greenSlider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [bSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(blueSlider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];




            CGPoint lastPoint = [sender locationOfTouch: sender.numberOfTouches - 1 inView: gradientView];
            CGPoint center = CGPointMake((size.width/2), (size.height /2));
            CGPoint delta = CGPointMake(lastPoint.x - center.x,  lastPoint.y - center.y);
            CGFloat angle = (delta.y == 0 ? delta.x >= 0 ? 0 : M_PI : atan2(delta.y, delta.x));
            angle = fmod(angle,  M_PI * 2.0);
            angle += angle >= 0 ? 0 : M_PI * 2.0;
            if((lastPoint.x - center.x) + (lastPoint.y - center.y)/2 < radius)
            {
                UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue: angle / (M_PI * 2.0) saturation:saturationSlider.value brightness:hellSlider.value alpha:alphaSlider.value];
                if ([color getRed: &r green: &g blue:&b alpha: &a])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Color value - R : %g G : %g : B %g", r*255, g*255, b*255);
                }
                float red = r;
                float green = g;
                float blue = b;
                rText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",rSlider.value];
                gText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",green*255];
                bText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",blue*255];


                colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(rText.text.floatValue/255) green:(gText.text.floatValue/255) blue:(bText.text.floatValue/255) alpha:alphaSlider.value];
                rSlider.value = red*255;
                gSlider.value = green*255;
                bSlider.value = blue*255;
                alphaText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",alphaSlider.value];
                brightnessText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",hellSlider.value];
                saturationText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",saturationSlider.value];

            }





        }
}
```

Question is solved, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you definitely 'can' add a crosshair at your current touch position.

I can tell you one of the many possible ways of doing this.

Implement the

```
 - (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```

action handler.

Load an image of a crosshair into an UIImage (say overlayImage):

```
  overlayImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"crosshair.png"];
```

and set it into an UIView (say overlayView).
[This can be done in your viewDidLoad method itself.]

Now, add the following code to your handlePan method:

```
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:colorView]; //whichever view you want.
_overlayView.center = CGPointMake(_overlayView.center.x + translation.x,
                                     _overlayView.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:colorView];

 if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:colorView];
    CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
    CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 800;
   // NSLog(@"magnitude: %f, slideMult: %f", magnitude, slideMult);

    float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult; // Increase for more of a slide
    CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(_overlayView.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor),
                                     _overlayView.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));
    finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 0), colorView.bounds.size.width);
    finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 0), colorView.bounds.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        _overlayView.center = finalPoint;
    } completion:nil];
```

That should do the trick.

You may also try doing this by implementing the touchesBegan and touchesMoved method.

Comment: will this crosshair follow the panning in real time?

Comment: will it interfere with the rest of my code? I'll edit the handlePan method i already have in here

Comment: I certainly hope not! Make sure you hide the overlaid UIView as soon as the touch is released.

Comment: could you try edit my code in your solution and picture where to implement the code? 

I'm a little confused with it

Comment: No need to change anything in your code right away... the loading of the image overlayImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"crosshair.png"]; can be put inside viewDidLoad. Don't forget to set this image into the overlay view. The snippet that goes into  (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender remains the same, just that the variable 'sender' has been termed 'recognizer' in my code. Append it to the end of your method and test.

Comment: let me know if you're stuck.

Comment: the overlayView works but the image is waaay too big. if i loaded the view with `initWithImage`, how do i set the size?

Comment: you may try adding this statement: overlayView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; btw, are you doing this through storyboard? make sure your UIView is of the right dimensions.

Comment: is there a way to set a specific rect size for the overlay?

Comment: Do this: overlayView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"crosshair.png"]];
        [overlayView setFrame:CGRectMake(20*scaleFX, 50*scaleFY, 280*scaleFX, 315*scaleFY)];//or whatever size you want
        overlayView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

Comment: is there any way to eliminate the slide and just follow the pan?

Comment: try setting the slideFactor to zero, or a very low value and see what happens. should help.

Comment: It worked but please check my question for the very last issue. i edited it

Comment: I solved it. thank you. I accepted your answer and voted you up!